# tightness of sequence of degenerate probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If $\delta_x$ denotes for $x\in \mathscr{R} $, the degenerate distribution at $x$, prove that the sequence $\delta_{x_n}$  of probabilities on $(\mathscr{R,B})$ is tight iff $x_n$ is bounded.

This is what I have done:
given $\delta_{x_n}$ is tight
implies $\delta_{x_n} [-M,M]>1-\varepsilon $
i.e., $P[-M\le X_n\le M] > 1-\varepsilon $
i.e., $P[-M\le x_n\le M] > 1-\varepsilon\to 1$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$
i.e $X_n$ is bounded almost surely
i.e., $x_n$ is bounded

if $x_n$ is bounded
implies $|x_n|\le M  \forall n \ge 1 $
implies $P(|X_n| \le M) = 1 $
implies $\delta_{x_n}[-M,M]>1-\varepsilon$
hence $\delta_{x_n}$ is tight.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but it seems that you are not getting the big picture: 
A sequence of dirac masses on $\mathbb{R}$ are basically equivalent to a sequence of reals in terms of compactness.

If $\delta_{x_n}$ is tight then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a compact, which we can assume to be of the form $[-M,M]$ such that for any $n$, $\delta_{x_n}([-M,M]) > 1-\varepsilon$. Since the dirac masses can only evaluate to $1$ or $0$ this means that for any $n$, $\delta_{x_n}([-M,M]) = 1 $ that is, any $x_n$ is in $[-M, M]$ and thus the sequence is bounded.

You can do the other implicance in a similar fashion.

Comment: thank you.I missed that point